# copy specific folders under main folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, unix

Think that I have a **main-folder**. Under **main-folder** there are **my-folder-x** type folders.
Under **my-folder-x** type folders there are both folders and some files.

```
-main-folder
 -my-folder-a
   -build-folder
   -demo-folder
   dummy.js
   dummy.css
   my.json
   -dummy-folder
 -my-folder-b
   -build-folder
   -demo-folder
   dummy.js
   dummy.css
   my.json
   -dummy-folder
 -my-folder-c
   -build-folder
   -demo-folder
   dummy.js
   dummy.css
   my.json
```

I want to copy that folders with specific folder/files.So I want to copy that folders to copied-folder like this:

```
-copied-folder
  -my-folder-a
    -build-folder
    -demo-folder
  -my-folder-b
     -build-folder
     -demo-folder
  -my-folder-c
     -build-folder
     -demo-folder
```

I need this to work on cross-platforms like Windows, Unix...

I'm trying ncp package.There is a filter option but I think it's for only filenames not folder.

https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp

Any idea?

Note:I also need files and folders to be copied under **build-folder** and **demo-folder**. It can be folders or files under that two types of folders.

Note2: The project is using npm. For example I use rimraf npm package to delete folders.It's cross platform.Both work on Windows and Mac

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

Comment: What about files under `build-folder` and `demo-folder` ?

Comment: I also need that files to be copied.

Comment: by cross-platform, do you mean you want it to work for users who have `bash` on Unix and `git-bash` on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This `find + cp` should work with gnu utilities installed on Unix, Windows, Mac etc:

```
cd main-folder
find . \( -path '*/build-folder/*' -o -path '*/demo-folder/*' \) \
-exec cp --parents '{}' copied-folder \;
```

[GNU Utils on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)